# Render normal text

Tags: apex, visualforce

I some text on my page and I want to render it when I clicked on command link.

```
<apex:commandlink> click here </apex:commandlink>

<apex:outputpanel id=click> 
display this content, no visualforce tags used just some text 
</apex:outputpanel>
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you taken a look at the **rerender** and **rendered** attributes on the Visualforce tag components? If you take a look at the [<apex:commandLink>](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_commandLink.htm), you can specify a list of IDs that you want to rerender upon a click - in this case, you have set your <apex:outputPanel> to the id of click (provided you wrap it in quotes). However, because you do not want this to happen immediately, you'll need to use the rendered attribute on the outputPanel tag to reference a variable or expression that originally evaluates to false, but upon clicking the commandLink gets flipped to true.

If you are using a custom controller or extension, and are adamant about using Visualforce, this is pretty simple as you can just create a public boolean variable to reference:

```
public Boolean displayText {get;set;}
```

As an example, your Apex and Visualforce might look like the following:

```
public with sharing MyController 
{
    public Boolean displayText {get;set;}
    public MyController()
    {
        displayText = false;
    }

    public void toggleDisplayText() 
    {
        displayText = !displayText;
    }
}

<apex:page controller="myController">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:commandLink value="Click Here" action="{!toggleDisplayText}" rerender="clickPanel"/>
        <apex:outputPanel id="clickPanel"> 
            <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!displayText}">
                display this content, no visualforce tags used just some text 
            </apex:outputPanel>
        </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

A few notes:

- You have to have nested outputPanels because your original outputPanel will not render at all, so a rerender won't be able to find it.
- You need to wrap the <apex:commandLink> tag inside an <apex:form> tag

However, if all you really want to do is make some text show up, it is probably easier to use something like Javascript or CSS to apply/remove a CSS class to your text that implements **display: none;**. Then you can use click handlers to toggle that. Take a look at the **show()** method in [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/show/).

Comment: @Micheal: Thanks, I just didn't understand why do I need two output panels?

Comment: I've come across issues when you initially load a page where the outputPanel doesn't render, it doesn't seem to evaluate the rerender. Here is a link pointing to someone else having similar issues: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums?id=906F0000000986vIAA